# Imager - connection refused error

Tags: plugin-imager

All assets on my website work properly, however I cannot resolve an issue with Imager plugin on a single page template.

My template:

```
    {% set profileImage = entry.user.photoUrl('original') %}
    {% set transform = {width: 90, height: 90, effects: { grayscale: true, gamma: 1.2 } } %}
    {% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(profileImage, transform|merge({width: 180, height: 180})).getUrl() %}

        {% if profileImage %}
            <figure>
                <span style="background-image: {{transformedImage}}">
                    <img src="{{ transformedImage }}"/>
                </span>
            </figure>
        {% endif %}
```

When I try to open a page which uses this template I got the Craft Exception:

> cURL error “7” encountered while attempting to download
>   “http://127.0.0.1:8001/cpresources/[...]/myImage.jpg/?d=1553875482”.
>   The error was: “Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8001: Connection
>   refused”

But when I open the image link directly it works normally. Checked permissions many times. What can be an issue here?

Thanks

Comment: When you open `“http://127.0.0.1:8001/cpresources/[...]/myImage.jpg/?d=1553875482` directly it works?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's why I'm not quite sure what's the issue

Comment: Several things here to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952676/curl-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-80

Comment: Thank you very much!! That was the case - I removed `::1 localhost` from my /etc/hosts and boom - everything works just fine!

Comment: Awesome... would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so @brad-bell suggested a fix and the solution was to disable `::1 localhost` rule from my /etc/hosts file. After that change all images are working properly.

More details can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952676/curl-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-80

Thanks!